# How to smoothly zoom a view using Option+mouse scroll events

Tags: macos, zooming

I am trying to implement smooth zoom in and out using mouse scroll + Option key but can't figure out how to do this.

Currently I have a ViewController that sets the frame size for the view to be zoomed, which is hosted in NSScrollView.

However this results in a very shaky zoom experience - has anyone got any suggestions on how to achieve a nice smooth zoom when using the mouse scroll wheel

```
/// Capture mouse scroll wheel events and send to zoom function with mouse location
    /// so we can zoom in to the location
    override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {

        guard event.modifierFlags.contains(.option) else {
            super.scrollWheel(with: event)
            return
        }

        let dy = event.deltaY
        if dy != 0.0 {

            self.scrollZoom(dy, location: event.locationInWindow)

        }
    }

    func scrollZoom(_ delta: CGFloat, location: CGPoint) {

        zoom += delta * scrollZoomSpeedMultiplier

        let frame = caLayoutView.frame
        let newSize = CGSize(width: frame.width*zoom, height: frame.height*zoom)
        let newOrigin = frame.origin // Need to calculate the origin but for now just get smooth zoom to work

        caLayoutView.animator().frame = CGRect(origin: newOrigin, size: newSize)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so this is completely ridiculous - I have spent days on this.  And all the underlying CALayers and images scale in vector - no pixellated bitmap scaling here. And it is blindingly fast with no stuttering or hesitation. To me scaling and magnification are two different things which is why I never even considered this before - and I am sure I did and got some pixellated mess - my bad.  Hope this saves someone else some time.

FYI I have a large pdf rendered in a background CALayer and then 100+ draggable objects each in their own CALayers on top of that. Now things zoom, scale and move as smoothly as any of the top end graphics packages e.g. Affinity Designer etc.

Still in shock and waiting for something to go all crazy.

```
   override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {

        guard event.modifierFlags.contains(.option) else {
            super.scrollWheel(with: event)
            return
        }

        let dy = event.deltaY
        if dy != 0.0 {

            let magnification = self.scrollView.magnification + dy/30
            let point = self.scrollView.contentView.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)

            self.scrollView.setMagnification(magnification, centeredAt: point)
        }
    }
```